# Explain this line from underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Can you explain me a line from this statement from *underscore.js*:

```
_.every = _.all = function(obj, iterator, context) {
    var result = true;

    each(obj, function(value, index, list) {
--->  if (!(result = result && iterator.call(context, value, index, list)))
          return breaker;
    });

    return !!result;
};
```

I don't understand this line `(result = result && iterator.call...` Why does he need `result` at the righ part of the equality. Does the author just want to convert `iterator.call(...)` to a boolean? For example what he wants to do is just

```
if (!(result = !!iterator.call(context, value, index, list))) // "!!" used
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference with your statement is that yours give to `result` the value of the last value of `!!iterator.call` while in the original code `result` is `false` as soon as `iterator.call` returns `false` for at least one iteration.

In the original code `result` is `true` only if `iterator.call` returned true for **all** iterations.

Comment: I agree that in the original code if the call returns *false*, it will never be called again. But in the code if *false* is assigned to `result` the function immidiately returns so particularly in this code my line would not change anything? No?

Comment: It returns from the callback passed to `each`, it doesn't break the loop.

Comment: `breakes` is an immutable object, if returned it breask the loop. My claim was that changin the original line to mine does not change the behaviour of the function.